# R Programming: How to add data labels in bar graph made by plotly?

Tags: r, charts, shiny, plotly

I am creating bar charts using plotly. But would like to know how can I add data labels on the top of the bar chart?

In the bar plot below I would like to add individual data labels on the bar graph.

I am using this code for generating bar graph:

```
plot_ly(
      x = as.vector(de$MO),
      y = de$CNT,
     text = a, hoverinfo = "text", mode="y", type = "bar",
      name = "SF Zo",
       color = as.character(de$MO)
    )%>%
      layout(title= paste("Monthly SOI Count of", clientName,"for the year",selectedYear, sep = " ") , xaxis = xQuartAxis, yaxis = yQuartAxis)
```

[Plot Created Using Plotly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0Dmg.png)

I hope now the question looks fine? If any other data is required kindly comment below.

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is not engaging: You're not explaining why this is an issue, whether you have tried anything yourself so far and not offering a working example. [This page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) might help you.

Comment: @sebastianmm sorry for that I am updating the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I got the answer. This not the exact answer but rather a hack which is proved useful at least for me.

```
plot_ly(
      x = as.vector(de$MO),
      y = de$CNT,
     text = a, hoverinfo = "text", mode="y", type = "bar",
      name = "SF Zo",
       color = as.character(de$MO)
    )%>%
      add_trace(data=de, x=as.vector(de$MO), y=de$CNT, mode="text",text=a, hoverinfo='none',textposition = "top middle", showlegend = FALSE)%>%
      layout(title= paste("Monthly SOI Count of", clientName,"for the year",selectedYear, sep = " ") , xaxis = xQuartAxis, yaxis = yQuartAxis)
```

Thanks :)